# Helm Grep within a first results set / multi line search

Tags: helm, search, grep

I would like to use helm to search for two terms which may well be on different lines.

Is there a way to grep for the first term then further grep within the resulting fileset the second term?

eg

```
Func(
   "hello"
);
```

I would like to grep/search for all files containing "Func" and then "hello".

I know I can save the results set to a hgrep buffer but I cant fathom how to then use that buffer's match fileset to narrow the search for the second term.

Comment: Does `M-x helm-do-grep-ag RET Func.*\n.*hello` work for you?

Comment: Would you accept alternatives to Helm? [Elgrep](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/elgrep) allows multiple search criteria. In your case there would be two alternatives: 1st) Give `"hello"` as first search term and `Func` as second one. Elgrep would search for all files containing `Func` and show you the matches for `"hello"` within those files. 2nd) Your example looks as you would actually want to find matches for a [`cexp`](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/cexp/). Elgrep allows you to specify the search function. You could choose `cexp-search-forward` and `Func\!("hello"\!)` as search string.